# Passing on KeyValuePair list from backgroundWorker1 to backgroundWorker2

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a little problem, I'm using

```
var filelist = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
 filelist.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(a, b));
 filelist.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(c,d));
```

in backgroundWorker1, to do what it needs to do, and when backgroundWorker1 is done, the list should be passed on to backgroundWorker2 somehow.

I have no clue where to even begin doing that so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What `BW2` does and is it started before `BW1`? Why you need two separate BWs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the first's RunWorkerCompleted start the second with an argument. Here's an example just for an idea of how to send an argument from the first to the second.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;

    backgroundWorker2.DoWork += backgroundWorker2_DoWork;
    backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker2_RunWorkerCompleted;

    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}


void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = "a";
}

void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string s = (string)e.Result;
    backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync(s);
}

void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = (string)e.Argument;
}

void backgroundWorker2_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Text = (string)e.Result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the list is visible to both workers and also an event variable (it can be an `AutoresetEvent` for example). Then when the work on the list is finished in `backgroundworker1`, signal the second worker to read it:

```
// prepare the list
event.Set();
```

In `backgroundworker2` you should wait at some point on the event:

```
event.WaitOne();
// use the list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply start the second BackgroundWorker in the delegate that you're using to handle the first BackgroundWorker's RunWorkerCompleted event.

Just set the args in the RunWorkerAsync call of BW#2 to the return value of BW#1.

It doesn't sound like BW#2 has anything to do before BW#1 has finished, so there's no point implementing shared state or raising events or implementing an observer-type pattern.

Comment: Do you actually mean RunWorkerAsync ?

Comment: @SurjitSamra - Yes, RunWorkerAsync